# How to alter text size on hover, without pushing the surroundings (html/css - no javascript)

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover, font-size

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rXf4U/5/

I don't think I can explain it any better than it's done in the title, but the example should be pretty self explanatory.

I have a finite about of space filled with tags, words or whatever. In order to make room for more, I've lowered the text-size, but want then to actually be readable when hovering. It is easy to see from the example wherein the problem lies.

I've tried just about everything, including a lot of searching. I've tried to use z-layers. I didn't expect it to work and of course it didn't. I've also tried various approached involving positioning, and while I have succeeded to some degree, it really is a mess.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rXf4U/17/

As this is not a new concept, I'm sure it's just be who are unable figure out the correct search term, but just the same, I'm stuck ;)

I do hope you'll guide me in the right direction.

Best regards.

Important edit:
Of course the li tag will contain link:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">keyword</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">keyword</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">keyword</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">keyword</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I do hope this makes it more "possible" to do without JavaScript.

Sorry for the screw up.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this effectively is to make use of javascript =[ Is that an option?

Comment: No, I absolute hate JavaScript and won't have it fronted. I did however forget an important point which may make a difference. Of course the li's will contain links or <a>'s. Guess that's pretty important. Big bummer for my part.

Answer (score 2):

You could use overflow hidden, whitespace: nowrap, and have each li element on different lines.  See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/rXf4U/37/) for an example.

Comment: Don't solve the problem in it's entirety, as the text is still pushed. Also it would require me to split things up in to columns. Guess that actually would make things prettier. Thanks for the answer-

Comment: @Zacariaz Welcome, hope this works for you or at least gets you closer to a solution.  Also, just a side note:  whenever I use overflow hidden, I usually consider adding a title with the same text being displayed, the main reason being I find it a bit annoying when text gets cut and you can't read it.  May or may not apply in your case, but just a thought :)

Answer (score 1):

This is, sort of, possible. But it's moderately hack-ish (and relatively fragile, given browser implementations of the `:after` pseudo-element), and also involves you adding a `title` attribute to the `li` elements, to create this mark-up:

```
<ul>
    <li title="picnic">picnic</li>
    <li title="webprogramming">webprogramming</li>
    <li title="scripting">scripting</li>
    <li title="stylesheet">stylesheet</li>
    <li title="jsfiddle">jsfiddle</li>
    <li title="stackoverflow">stackoverflow</li>
    <li title="moonwalker">moonwalker</li>
    <li title="powertools">powertools</li>
    <li title="mastermind">mastermind</li>
    <li title="chicken">chicken</li>
</ul>
```

and the following CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
}
li:hover:after {
    color: #f00;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXf4U/36/).

Comment: Wow, that is some solution. There is one catch though. I need to be sure it will work in newer browser, not including IE8 for now, and it need to work in future browsers too. I will investigate further regarding this approach. For now, that's for the nice answer.

Comment: I should probably note that the li's will eventually contain a <a> tag. Suppose that's actually pretty important :D

Comment: @Zacariaz, I'm not sure, really. It might be, can you show your intended mark-up? This solution will work in css3-compliant browsers and, probably, be compatible for quite some time (in the same way Firefox 4/Chromium 11 currently support the earliest incarnations of CSS). The only problem, really, is likely to be the IE family.

Comment: well, it seems to work in IE9, and I have yet to decide if I want to support ie8. If someone could check out how it works, that would be great, otherwise I'll return when I know more. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zacariaz, no problem at all; glad to be of help :)